# Why does Pylint warn "Redefining name from outer scope" against default parameter?

Tags: python, scope, variable-assignment, pylint

```py
def print_name(your_name = "Anonymous Andy"):
    print("Hello, " + your_name)

def your_name():
    # This function has same name as variable in above function
    return None

print_name() # Prints "Hello, Anonymous Andy"
print_name("World") # Prints "Hello, World"
```

Above code is written for academic purpose to learn Python, and not for production. Pylint (2.14.0) warns me:

> `1:15: W0621: Redefining name 'your_name' from outer scope (line 4) (redefined-outer-name)`

## Question

1. I assume Pylint is warning me "Hey you are redefining the *your_name* function". Is this understanding correct?
2. If above understanding is correct then I think Pylint is **wrong**, and I think I am redefining the *your_name* variable which is local to the *print_name* function's scope. Is this understanding correct?
3. If my above understandings are correct, I am further puzzled because I don't think a famous program like Pylint would raise such false alarm. The fact that it raised an alarm is not wrong, but the message looks like a lie because I'm **not** redefining anything from outer scope. Am I missing something?

Comment: because the argument `your_name` is hiding the function with the same name

Comment: Your understanding is correct that you're only redefining the variable within the scope of `print_name`, but this is not a "false alarm".  Imagine how confused you'd be if you tried to call the `your_name` function from inside `print_name`, not realizing that you'd carelessly redefined `your_name` to something else within that scope.  "Why does it work in all my other functions but give me a `TypeError` inside this one???"  Linter warnings are there to help you avoid forehead-smacking moments like that.

Comment: @Samwise Thanks for validating my understanding. If I **try** to call the `your_name` function from inside `print_name`, Python will complain "`your_name` is a string, and you can't call it" with a straight face. So if Pylint was to warn me (which is helpful), shouldn't the message be something like "You're using a confusing/existing name"?

Comment: "Redefining name" means the same thing as "you're using an existing name".  Pylint errors tend toward brevity since you sometimes find yourself scrolling through a lot of them.  They usually take a bit of puzzling the first time you see them (like you did here) but they soon become like old friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No. Functions are interpreted before their parameters, and within the module, are defined in the "outer scope". Your code would be interpreted the same as this; therefore, the error would make more sense, visually.

```
def your_name():
    return None

def print_name(your_name = "Anonymous Andy"):
    print("Hello, " + your_name)
```

If you were to redefine a local variable, that would look like this

```
def print_name(your_name = "Anonymous Andy"):
    your_name = ""
    print("Hello, " + your_name)
```